# Chosing between several options in listBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have C# WinForm project and listBox on the main form. I need to check what item is selected by user and then do action appropriate to selected item.
I was trying to use Timer in Form.Load, so when the Form is loaded it starts periodically with Timer Interval call for my check function.
But when i select any item on my list nothing hapens. I also tried insert Timer in an endless While(true)  cycle. It was the error then.

```
System.Timers.Timer tmr = new System.Timers.Timer();
tmr.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Checking_Options);
tmr.Interval = 10; //
tmr.Enabled = true; //                  

public void Checking_Options(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    
   switch (listBox2.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
```

How can this be realise properly?

Comment: Why use a timer to check when you can use `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the list box?

Comment: Use the [`SelectedIndexChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged).

Comment: Ok, thanks. It turns out to be done so easily.

Comment: Why the MVS tag? MVS is a mainframe operating system.

Comment: Am I the only one that believes it's super odd, that OP doesn't know about UI events but knows about this timer approach? Especially in a world of intellisense where when someone types `listBox2.SelectedIndex` you are getting greated with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8VV2.png - which lists the event `SelectedIndexChanged` - I am really puzzled as to how this isn't the obvious solution? OP seems to know how events work, as OP describes to the `Elapsed` event, but how could it be possible to not stumble accross the `SelectedIndexChanged`. (I don't mean it rude in anyway, I am just surprised)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should go to the Properties page, then switch to the Events tab and add SelectedIndexChanged event.

[image: Add SelectedIndexChanged event]